# Sql Reporting Service Catalog Id changes when deployed

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a project which uses SQL Reporting Service.  In the project I have a UI to declare existing reports to their systems, so they don't have to see all reports which they don't need.  To do this declaration I’m using CatalogId at ReportServer database, catalog table in my table to takes the data.  But when I deploy reports to the server, CatalogId changes and this creates a big problem for me.

Is the ReportServer keeping the changes on server?

How can I get the new CatalogId via using old CatalogId?

Answer (score 0):

First to attempt to answer your question you should be using the ItemID in the Catalog table of the ReportServer database.  This GUID is maintained and will persist if the report is re-deployed.  It only changes if the report is deleted and re-deployed.

These ItemID's will only be maintained if the report was ran.  You can find the legacy GUID as ReportID in the ExecutionLogStorage table.  The ELS only stores data to whatever you have the "ExecutionLogDaysKept" setting set to in the ConfigurationInfo table.

Secondly a custom UI is unnecessary as with proper folder structure you can maintain report permissions through Active Directory groups.  The individual in the groups without permissions to reports do not see them.